# Tracking memory usage of an Actor flow

Tags: java, akka, actor

I am developing an app which has Akka Actors in the backend. It is a very simple app in which developers can code certain computations using a GUI and the result is shown in the UI. Its kind of similar to [MIT Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/). Each component is an Actor in the backend.

Now my question is how do I track the memory usage of a single code snippet. I don't want a single flow to consume more memory and crash the entire system. In some way I want to meter the memory usage of an Akka Actor individually and then if it crosses a threshold, the system will kill it. Ideally I would wan't the CPU usage also to be measured as well, but I figured that I would start with memory since it is simpler. Is there a way to do this using our own code/an open source plugin? I am aware that lightbend telemetry has commercial add-ons but I was wondering if it can be done using open source stuff.

Comment: have you tried kamon(http://kamon.io/documentation/1.x/instrumentation/akka/)

Comment: can you describe how the system is setup? Are all the actors in 1 single JVM process, or are they spread out using cluster or remote actors? You could use JMX if you want to monitor the entire process, or use `instrumentation` internally.